# Access data from OneDrive

Tags: sas

I've been searching for an answer on the Internet for the past few days and couldn't find any, so I'm posting the question here. Is there any way I can read SAS datasets that are stored in OneDrive without downloading or synchronizing it?

Is there any libname statement?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use OneDrive, so I don't know how it works. But if you have a direct web-address like: onedrive.com/username/file.sas7bdat, then I know a code for importing Excel dataset. But I might work for SAS dataset too, at least you can try. The code is from the [website](http://www.listendata.com/2013/09/importing-excel-data-into-sas.html).

```
FILENAME website url "http://www2.census.gov/acs2005/Tables_Profiles_Subject_Tables/010Nation/United%20States.xls" debug;               


PROC IMPORT OUT= Readin DATAFILE= website                                                                                                                                                                                                            

RUN;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can not read a dataset without downloading it.
You need to map a local drive to your OneDrive account. There is a description of the process [here](http://thetechl33t.com/2014/03/14/how-to-mount-your-onedrive-as-a-local-mapped-drive/). When this is done, you can apply a normal BASE engine libname statement to that drive.

Comment: Are you sure? Years since I've used SAS, but iirc it has a libname interface to WebDAV, and I think onedrive has WebDAV available.

Comment: When I said "you can't read a dataset without downloading it" it was more a technical observation. If you map a local drive or use a webdav engine doesn't really matter, the data will still get transferred to the machine where the SAS session is running.